# OpenCV python canny Required argument 'threshold2' (pos 4) not found

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to isolate text from an image with openCV before sending it to tesseract4 engine to maximize results.

I found this [interesting post](http://www.danvk.org/2015/01/07/finding-blocks-of-text-in-an-image-using-python-opencv-and-numpy.html) and I decided to copy the source and try by mysdelf

However I am getting issue with the [first call to OpenCV](https://gist.github.com/luipillmann/d76eb4f4eea0320bb35dcd1b2a4575ee#file-crop_morphology-py-L249)

To reproduce:

1. Simply copy the code from the gist
2. launch command `script.py /path/to/image.jpg`

I am getting issue:
`Required argument 'threshold2' (pos 4) not found`

Do you maybe have an idea of what does it means.
I am a javascript, java and bash script developer but not python...

In a simple version:

```
import glob
import os
import random
import sys
import random
import math
import json
from collections import defaultdict

import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import rank_filter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2 and '*' in sys.argv[1]:
        files = glob.glob(sys.argv[1])
        random.shuffle(files)
    else:
        files = sys.argv[1:]

    for path in files:
        out_path = path.replace('.jpg', '.crop.png')
        if os.path.exists(out_path): continue
        orig_im = Image.open(path)
        edges = cv2.Canny(np.asarray(orig_im), 100, 200)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This is not a proper way of asking a question on SO. Localize your problem, post minimal code where you can reproduce the said problem.

Comment: @Geoffrey don't link to other sites... write a minimal version of that code here so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: Edited with steps to reproduce

Comment: Could you add the exact error to your question? where in your code does this error occur: `Required argument 'threshold2' (pos 4) not found`

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you on? `threshold2` is indeed one of the `Canny` arguments. What happens with `cv2.Canny(np.asarray(orig_im), 100, 200, None, None, None)`?

Comment: The issue is coming from a wrong version of opencv. I am using 3.3 and this is interface for 2.x I adapted my code to 3.3 and it is working. Now I have other issues

Comment: Answer your own question then with your solution, and post a new question with your other issues if they're unrelated and you can't figure them out.

Comment: The newest 3.3 version has *two* methods for `Canny`, one that you can provide custom gradients with `Canny(dx, dy, edges, threshold1, threshold2, L2gradient=false)` which is newer, and the old-style `Canny(image, threshold1, threshold2, edges=None, apertureSize=3, L2gradient=false)`. For some reason with the image type that `PIL` returned, OpenCV tried to use the first-type I mentioned, which is strange. That's why it was saying it couldn't find `threshold2` which is the FOURTH argument in the other `Canny` (like your error says), while it's the THIRD argument in the standard `Canny()`.

Comment: But your answer is better than mine. Do you maybe know how I can force to use the second one?

Comment: It should know to call which one based on the arguments you specified, and AFAIK you called it the right way (this works for me, but I'm on 3.2). Can you try to display the image and ensure that it's being read correctly before passing it into `Canny`?

Comment: FWIW it looks like this other version of `Canny` was introduced in OpenCV 3.2.0 and there's no Python documentation for it yet; newest Python documentation is for 3.0.0. Oddly enough if I specify incorrect arguments OpenCV assumes I meant to use this newer version; if I try `edges = cv2.Canny()` I get `TypeError: Required argument 'dx' (pos 1) not found` even though `image` is the first parameter in the standard implementation of `Canny`. But if I call with three args where the first one is a `np.array` and the other two are `int`s it calls the standard `Canny` with `image` as the first arg.

Comment: I think I've narrowed down the problem. Solution incoming.

Comment: Was the original code causing the problem really `edges = cv2.Canny(np.asarray(orig_im), 100, 200)` and not `edges = cv2.Canny(orig_im, 100, 200)`? I can see why the latter one would do it, but the former doesn't reproduce it here.

Comment: @Geoffrey Also, what version of PIL are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** okay so this answer is apparently wrong, as I tried to send my own 16-bit int image into the function and couldn't reproduce the results.

**Edit2:** So I *can* reproduce the error with the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2

orig_im = Image.open('opencv-logo2.png')

threshold1 = 50
threshold2 = 150
edges = cv2.Canny(orig_im, 50, 100)
```

> TypeError: Required argument 'threshold2' (pos 4) not found

So if the image was *not* cast to an array, i.e., the `Image` class was passed in, I get the error. The PIL `Image` class is a class with a lot of things other than the image data associated to it, so casting to a `np.array` is necessary to pass into functions. But if it was properly cast, everything runs swell for me.

In a chat with [Dan Mašek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%C5%A1ek), my idea below is a bit incorrect. It is true that the newer `Canny()` method needs 16-bit images, but the bindings don't look into the actual numpy `dtype` to see what bit-depth it is to decide which function call to use. Plus, if you try to actually send a `uint16` image in, you get a different error:

```
edges = cv2.Canny(np.array([[0, 1234], [1234, 2345]], dtype=np.uint16), 50, 100)
```

> error: (-215) depth == CV_8U in function Canny

So the answer I originally gave (below) is not the total culprit. Perhaps you accidentally removed the `np.array()` casting of the `orig_im` and got that error, *or*, something else weird is going on.

---

**Original (wrong) answer**

In OpenCV 3.2.0, a new method for `Canny()` was introduced to allow users to specify their own gradient image. In the original implementation, `Canny()` would use the `Sobel()` operator for calculating the gradients, but now you could calculate say the `Scharr()` derivatives and pass *those* into `Canny()` instead. So that's pretty cool. But what does this have to do with your problem?

The `Canny()` method is overloaded. And it decides which function you want to use based on the arguments you send in. The original call for `Canny()` with the required arguments looks like

```
cv2.Canny(image, threshold1, threshold2)
```

but the new overloaded method looks like

```
cv2.Canny(grad_x, grad_y, threshold1, threshold2)
```

Now, there was a hint in your error message:

> Required argument 'threshold2' (pos 4) not found

Which one of these calls had `threshold2` in position 4? The newer method call! So why was that being called if you only passed three args? Note that you were getting the error if you used a `PIL` image, but not if you used a `numpy` image. So what else made it assume you were using the new call?

If you check the [OpenCV 3.3.0 `Canny()` docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de), you'll see that the original `Canny()` call requires an **8-bit input image** for the first positional argument, whereas the new `Canny()` call requires a **16-bit x derivative of input image (CV_16SC1 or CV_16SC3)** for the first positional argument.

Putting two and two together, PIL was giving you a 16-bit input image, so OpenCV thought you were trying to call the new method.

So the solution here, if you wanted to continue using PIL, is to convert your image to an 8-bit representation. `Canny()` needs a single-channel (i.e. grayscale) image to run, first off. So you'll need to make sure the `image` is single-channel first, and then scale it and change the numpy `dtype`. I believe PIL will read a grayscale image as single channel (OpenCV by default reads all images as three-channel unless you tell it otherwise).

If the image is 16-bit, then the conversion is easy with numpy:

```
img = (img/256).astype('uint8')
```

This assumes `img` is a numpy array, so you would need to cast the PIL image to `ndarray` first with `np.array()` or `np.asarray()`.

And then you should be able to run `Canny()` with the original function call.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was coming from an incompatibility between interfaces used and openCV version.

I was using openCV 3.3 so the correct way to call it is:

```
orig_im = cv2.imread(path)
edges = cv2.Canny(orig_im, 100, 200)
```

Comment: The version then wasn't your actual problem---you were calling the function fine (note your call to `Canny` is identical), but PIL was reading your image incorrectly.

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry but I am really new to python and I really have to find a way to have this working urgently.